# Getting same list for two tabs in tabs with listview on start of activity

Tags: android, listview, tabs

So,I have this activity which has tabs with listviews in them, and the problems I'm facing are:

The first and second tabs are having the same content i.e. the content the second tab should have is in first and second tab.

The third tab has correct content, though this is because it only instantiates just first and second tabs initially.
When I set
`mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);`

all the three tabs have same content, which is that of the third tab.

But after i've scrolled to third tab and then scroll back to the first one, the first one refreshes and has correct content.

Also, the next problem is the second tab never refreshes,because its always on the right or left to the tab which is opened.
I want the tabs to refresh every time they are opened since i'll be constantly changing the material in the lists.

```
package com.towntrot.anil.towntrot_eventmanager_02;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SlidingTabsBasicFragment extends Fragment {

ListView list;
public ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
public guestlist gg;
private SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private String[] eventtype={"CHECKED IN","CHECKED OUT","WAITING"};

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
    mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
}

class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object o) {
        return o == view;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return eventtype[position];
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.pager_item,
                container, false);
        guestlist gg=(guestlist)getActivity();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("");
        sb.append(position);
        String strI = sb.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),strI,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        setListData(gg.getNamelist(), gg.getStatuslist(), gg.getNo0fPeople(), position);
        list= ( ListView )view.findViewById(R.id.list);
        CustomAdapter adapter;
        adapter=new CustomAdapter( getActivity(), CustomListViewValuesArr);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        container.addView(view);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

}
public void setListData(String[] string,String[] status,int no,int pos) {
    CustomListViewValuesArr.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < no; i++) {

        final ListModel name = new ListModel();
        int x=Integer.parseInt(status[i]);
        if(pos==x){ name.setCompanyName(string[i]);
        CustomListViewValuesArr.add(name);}
    }
}


}
```

Please help me, I've seen a lot of answers but couldn't solve this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: obviously you do not understand your own(?) code ... all 3 adapters(ListView, not pager) using the same "data" ...

Comment: @Selvin but i initialised it inside the function so it must go out of scope after the call

Comment: interesting ... scope of CustomListViewValuesArr  is ... well whole SlidingTabsBasicFragment instance... so even if you will create many instance of SamplePagerAdapter inside this fragment it will be always the same variable(think about  CustomListViewValuesArr  as a static member for all non static classes inside class)  ...

Comment: @Selvin but the value of CustomListViewValuesArr is constantly being changed

Comment: FSM save us ... hehehe where ... only in setListData ... please back here if you will be able to write the code on the papper and tell what every lines do .. now, every explenations are like telling about colours to the blind man

Comment: @Selvin every time instantiateItem is called, CustomListViewValuesArr is cleaned and then filled with different unique values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are calling `setListData` every time a pager item is intantiated, which in turn populates the `CustomListViewValuesArr` with data of the given position. Then your list adapters are directly using this array cause it's defined in your fragment and depending on the last instantiated item, it's contents change.

Change `CustomListViewValuesArr` to a local variable; create a new `ArrayList<ListModel>` object in your `setListData` method and return it, use the returned object as your `CustomAdapter` constructor parameter.

Comment: Really Thank you, I'm very new to android app development but you guys just make it such a great experience.

Comment: @Dracontis can you tell me how to make the second tab refresh